# Plotting multiple subplots, each showing relation between two columns of a pandas DataFrame using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, relplot

I have a *pandas* [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ9aH.png) as follows:

`df=pd.DataFrame({'depth':[499,500,501,502,503],'parameter1':[25,29,24,23,25],'parameter2':[72,80,65,64,77]})`

I wish to plot multiple (two in this case) seaborn *lineplots* under the same graph, as subplots.
I want to keep the ***depth*** parameter constant on the *x-axis* but vary the *y-axis* parameters as per the other column values.

`sns.relplot(x='depth',y="parameter1",kind='line',data=df)`

[**parameter1 vs depth**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wMt9.png)

`sns.relplot(x='depth',y="parameter2",kind='line',data=df)`

[**parameter2 vs depth**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyPCi.png)

I have tried to use `seaborn.FacetGrid()` but I haven't obtained proper results with these.

Let me know how I can plot these graphs as subplots under a single graph without having to define them individually.

Comment: `sns.relplot` is a `FacetGrid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If plotting with `pandas` is an option, this works:

```
df.plot(x= 'depth', layout=(1,2),subplots=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,4))
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[image]

Furthermore, if you would like you can add `seaborn` styling on top:

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
df.plot(x= 'depth', layout=(1,2),subplots=True,sharey=True, figsize=(10.5,4))
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To use `FacetGrid`, you have to transform your dataframe in "long-form" using `melt()`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'depth':[499,500,501,502,503],'parameter1':[25,29,24,23,25],'parameter2':[72,80,65,64,77]})
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['depth'])

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df2, col='variable')
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, x='depth', y='value')
```

[image]

Note that the same output can be achieved more simply using `relplot` instead of creating the `FacetGrid` "by hand"

```
sns.relplot(data=df2, x='depth', y='value', col='variable', kind='line')
```